# I need to calculate the average ratings of films in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, average, rdd, calculation

I have a set of films data/ratings, and I need to calculate the average of the ratings by film. It's like a sum on ratings groupby movieId in SQL.
Thank you very much for your help

I've tried to use aggregateBYKey, but I don't know how to use seqOp and CombOp functions. I'm new to PySpark.

here is a chunk of my RDD: [movieId, userId, rating, film]

```
[('1', '1', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '5', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '7', 4.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '15', 2.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '17', 4.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '18', 3.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '19', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '21', 3.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '27', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '31', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '32', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '33', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '40', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '43', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '44', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '45', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '46', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '50', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '54', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '57', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)')]
```

I need to calculate the average rating for each film, something like:

```
[('1', average_ratings_of_film_1, film_name_1),
('2', average_ratings_of_film_2, film_name_2)]
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: you can do groupby and take average `df.groupBy("movie").avg("rating").show()`

Comment: thank you Pig, this solves it, but I need to do it using RDD's :/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to convert your list to a DF and then use `groupby().avg()`

```
data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
[('1', '1', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '5', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '7', 4.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '15', 2.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '17', 4.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '18', 3.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '19', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '21', 3.5, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '27', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '31', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '32', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '33', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '40', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '43', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '44', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '45', 4.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '46', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '50', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '54', 3.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
 ('1', '57', 5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)')])

df = data.toDF(schema=["movie_id", "user_id", "rating", "movie"])

group = df.groupby("movie").avg("rating")
group.show()
#+----------------+-----------+
#|           movie|avg(rating)|
#+----------------+-----------+
#|Toy Story (1995)|      3.875|
#+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: thank you Pissal for your answer, this solves it using dataframes indeed. But do I do it using RDD's ? that's the purpose of the project I'm working on :/ (I know RDD is quite obsolete against DataFrames and Datasets, but I'm compelled to do it using RDD's :/.

Comment: Please refer to this answer to know why Dataframe is better than an RDD. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367567/what-does-rdd-mean-in-pyspark-dataframe/58367841#58367841

Comment: SHORT : In general, it is recommended to use a DataFrame where possible due to the built in query optimization.