# What does rdd mean in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to to pyspark. I am wondering what does rdd mean in pyspark dataframe.

```
weatherData = spark.read.csv('weather.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

These two line of the code has the same output. I am wondering what the effect of having rdd

```
weatherData.collect()
weatherData.rdd.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data frame is a table, or two-dimensional array-like structure, in which each column contains measurements on one variable, and each row contains one case.

So, a `DataFrame` has additional metadata due to its tabular format, which allows Spark to run certain optimizations on the finalized query.

An `RDD`, on the other hand, is merely a **R**esilient **D**istributed **D**ataset that is more of a blackbox of data that cannot be optimized as the operations that can be performed against it, are not as constrained.

However, you can go from a `DataFrame` to an `RDD` via its `.rdd` method, and you can go from an RDD to a DataFrame (if the RDD is in a tabular format) via the `.toDF()` method

In general, it is recommended to use a DataFrame where possible due to the built in query optimization.